# Enum placeholder in library class

Tags: java, enums, annotations

I'm creating a very general annotation processor (e.g. xjc) which scans my source and generates extra classes based on it.  Ideally the domain-specific library should depend on the annotation processor library (which has no knowledge of the domain).

Two of the fields that I'm placing in the annotation processor are minVersion and maxVersion.  The code would look something like this:

```
@ProcessMe(minVersion=Version.1_3_5, maxVersion=Version.1_5)
private Foo fieldFoo;
```

The goal would be for the annotation processor to create an object which only does special processing if the version of the request is between 1.3.5 and 1.5.

Unfortunately, for this to work, the annotation processor needs to know about `@ProcessMe` and `@ProcessMe` needs to know about `Version` and `Version` is domain specific.

My original thought was that I would have a VersionInfo interface which Version implements (all I need is to be able to enumerate the possible values and compare them).  Unfortunately, even if VersionInfo extends Enum I am unable to specify it in the annotation as annotations can only include primitive, string, class, annotation, enumeration, and 1-D arrays of the above.

So, can anyone think of a way to make this work that doesn't require the annotation processor to have domain specific knowledge (the version is domain specific because one product may use a completely different versioning scheme than another product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following.

Define interface `ProcessorFilter` into your general library. This interface should look like

```
interface ProcessorFilter {
   boolean shouldProcess(Element element); 
}
```

All implementation of this processor are done in domain specific library.

In your case:

```
class DomainProcessorFilter {
    public boolean shouldProcess(Element element) {
        //returns true if element is annotated with ProcessMe and version is OK
    }
}
```

Your general library should discover all implementations of `ProcessorFilter` in classpath and run them. You can use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) for this.

Comment: Hmm...the problem is the annotation processor sees the code before it's compiled, so even if I find an instance of ProcessorFilter I can't instantiate it.  I suppose I could rewrite the entire apt process to use Reflections and load it up at start time.  Also, I could have 3 libraries, the general processor library, the domain specific library, and a domain specific processor plugin.  This gives me some things to think about.

Comment: @Pace, good luck with this. Implementation of annotation processing is very hard work.